# Object not printing/returning information to HTML(using jquery .hover())?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table in which I have two ids, `mPoint` and `bPoint`. I want to insert data here using `html()` when I hover over elements with id `hydrogen` or `helium`.

```
<div class="info" id="hydrogen">
    <em>1</em>
    H    
    <p>Hydrogen</p>
</div>
<div class="info" id="helium">
    <em>2</em>
    Li
    <p>Helium</p>
</div>

<table class="propTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Melting Point</td>
        <td id="mPoint"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Boiling Point</td>
        <td id="bPoint"></td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the JS Function

```
function PropElements() {
    var propHydrogen = { 
        "m_point": "14.01", 
        "b_point": "20.28"
    };
    var propHelium = { 
        "m_point": "0", 
        "b_point": "4.22"
    };

    $('.info').hover(function() {
        var getId = this.id;
        var getPropName = "prop" + getId.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + getId.slice(1);
        console.log(getPropName);
        $("#mPoint").html(getPropName.m_point + " K");
        $("#bPoint").html(getPropName.b_point + " K");
    }, function() {
        $("#mPoint").html("unknown");
        $("#bPoint").html("unknown");
    });
}
```

Here are two objects for Hydrogen and Helium. `getPropName` will change the name of the hovered element such that it becomes `prop[hoveredElementID]`. Now If I hover over div with `#hydrogen`, `getPropName` will change name to `propHydrogen`, which is also the name of the object. And then using `html()`, it should print the value of `m_point` and `b_point` at the position of specified IDs.

But its showing the value of `getPropName.m_point` and `getPropName.b_point` as unknown. I have tried putting the objects inside the function but it still returns unknown even though console is returning the exact propName that should work. I tried using `innerHTML`, but that returns undefined instead.

Though, If I use the name directly(`propHydrogen.m_point`), it prints the value correctly. What could be the problem here?

Comment: FYI You have plain old JS objects, nothing to do with JSON. I've amended the title and question accordingly to save confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you cannot dynamically use the value of a variable to point to another defined variable in the manner you are attempting. A better method would be to use a single object to store all information required and then access the properties of that object dynamically. Try this:

```
function propElements() {
    var elements = {
        hydrogen: { 
            "m_point": "14.01", 
            "b_point": "20.28"
        },
        helium: { 
            "m_point": "0", 
            "b_point": "4.22"
        }
    };

    $('.info').hover(function() {
        $("#mPoint").html(elements[this.id].m_point + " K");
        $("#bPoint").html(elements[this.id].b_point + " K");
    }, function() {
        $("#mPoint").html("unknown");
        $("#bPoint").html("unknown");
    });
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ez0tfdqk/)

Note that by making the property names in the object match the `id` of the `.info` elements it saves a lot of unnecessary string manipulation.